# What does `##` mean in C?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

This is an excerpt from linux kernel source. What is the `stem##` usage? seeing for first time in c

```
#define __pcpu_size_call_return(stem, variable)                         \
({      typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;                                    \
    __verify_pcpu_ptr(&(variable));                                 \
    switch(sizeof(variable)) {                                      \
    case 1: pscr_ret__ = stem##1(variable);break;                   \
    case 2: pscr_ret__ = stem##2(variable);break;                   \
    case 4: pscr_ret__ = stem##4(variable);break;                   \
    case 8: pscr_ret__ = stem##8(variable);break;                   \
    default:                                                        \
            __bad_size_call_parameter();break;                      \
    }                                                               \
    pscr_ret__;                                                     \
 })
```

Comment: Basic preprocessor functionality, like `##` operator, is something you can read about in any book on C. That is always a good idea. This place is mostly for questions that you might still have *after* reading the book.

Comment: Also, the Linux kernel is probably the last place you should go looking if you want to learn proper, readable, standard C programming...

Comment: And please choose a more suitable question title if you are asking. Often this is the first step to a solution.

Comment: @Lundin is right, the kernel is where you go if you want your head to explode :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `##` operator is a preprocessor operation which glues together tokens to form a *single* token.

So say you want to call two functions based on a common prefix, passing a single argument each time and allowing it to be changed.

You cannot use:

```
#define CallBoth(pref,arg) \
{ \
    arg = pref A (arg); \
    arg = pref B (arg); \
}
```

because the substituted `pref` and `A` (or `B`) will be *distinct* tokens. Similarly, you cannot use:

```
#define CallBoth(pref,arg) \
{ \
    arg = prefA (arg); \
    arg = prefB (arg); \
}
```

because no substitution of `prefA` or `prefB` will take place.

To do this, you use:

```
#define CallBoth(pref,arg) \
    { \
        arg = pref##A(arg); \
        arg = pref##B(arg); \
    }
```

and the substituted `pref` and `A` (or `B`) are concatenated into a single token. That way, if you enter:

```
CallBoth(xyzzy,intVar);
```

it will be translated to:

```
{
    intVar = xyzzyA(intVar);
    intVar = xyzzyB(intVar);
}
```

Without this feature, there's no way to end up with a single token representing the function name.

---

As stated in a comment in the file you're referencing:

> **/* Branching function to split up a function into a set of functions that are called for different scalar sizes of the objects handled. */**

So, depending on the size of the variable being given to the macro, it will call one of:

```
stem1(variable)
stem2(variable)
stem4(variable)
stem8(variable)
```

where `stem` and `variable` are supplied as a parameter to the macro. Or it will call `__bad_size_call_parameter()` if *none* of those sizes are relevant.

So, a call:

```
char char_var;
__pcpu_size_call_return(xyzzy,char_var)
```

will result in a call:

```
xyzzy1(char_var):

int int_var;
__pcpu_size_call_return(xyzzy,int_var)
```

will result in a call:

```
xyzzy4(int_var)
```

where `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: I think `#` is "stringising", `##` is "token pasting" ?

Comment: @Paul, I think you may be right. Actually, the standard just calls them the `#` and `##` operators so I'll go with that for now.

Comment: Thank you very much @paxdiablo for such a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 9):

The preprocessor operator `##` provides a way to concatenate actual arguments during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement text is adjacent to a `##`, the parameter is replaced by the actual argument, the ## and surrounding white space are removed, and the result is re-scanned. For example, the macro paste concatenates its two arguments:

```
#define paste(front, back) front ## back
```

so `paste(name, 1)` creates the token `name1`.